# Html & Css: Video backgroud adapt monitor size

Tags: html, css, video

i need to use a mp4 video as background. 
I would like the video to adapt to the size of the screen and not overlap with what is underneath.
I write:

```
<video autoplay loop muted poster="<?php echo $wo['config']['theme_url'];?>/img/1-s.png" id="bgvid">
         <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
         <source src="<?php echo $wo['config']['theme_url'];?>/video/1bis.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- Safari / iOS video    -->
</video>
```

And my css is:

```
video#bgvid { 
  position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
  width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100; 
  background-size: cover; 
  z-index: 0;
}
```

by assigning "top: 0", I would like the video to be displayed with:

```
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Matteo is better positioning 50% left and top and after traslate the video to center it inside the page.

With z-index you can use negative number. If the video is used for background, add `z-index: -1`. In this way the other object stay over the video.

```css
body {
  padding:0;
}

video {
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


<h1>
 PAGE TITLE
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fullscreen_video that I think is the best solution for your case.
The key of your problem is the position of the video.

```
#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Hope it helps!